# Idiom for script directory in python application?

Tags: python, django, python-import

I have a python application (Django based), and I have a couple of standalone maintenance scripts that go along with the application, that I have to call every now and then. They have to import parts of my application (sub-packages). Currently, I just put them in my toplevel directory:

```
application/
  djangoproject/
  djangoapp/
  otherpackage/
  tool1.py
  tool2.py
```

Where `tool1.py` would do

```
from djangoproject import wsgi
from djangoapp.models import Poll
```

I've accumulated quite some of these tools, and would like to move them to a `scripts` subdirectory. Then, I would like to be able to call them via `python scripts/tool1.py` or maybe `cd scripts; python tool1.py`.

I understand (and sometimes lament) how Python's imports work, and I know that I can add some lines to each script to add the parent directory to `PYTHONPATH`. I am wondering if there is a widespread pattern to handle such a collection of assorted scripts. Maybe one could put the path manipulation into another file, and have every script start with `import mainproject`?

I am using a virtualenv, and installing dependencies with pip. But the application itself currently doesn't use a `setup.py`, and I think it wouldn't help to move the scripts to a separate package installed via pip, since I change them a lot during development, and there are lots of one-offs.

Comment: If these scripts are are doing stuff for your django app, you might consider writing [custom mangement commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) instead. You can also put the scripts in their own package/directory and add that directory to the env `PATH` variable in your venv's activate script.

Answer (score 1):

The ways for organizing the source code vary from project to project. From the years of my experience, the best and the most pythonic way is to always have `setup.py`.

In that case, you can make `pip install -e .` and the [editable version](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) from `.` dir will be pseudo-installed to the virtualenv. Actually, not really installed (i.e. copied), but "linked": the source code dir will be added to `sys.path` with `.pth` files, so you can edit & try without any special copying/installing steps afterward.

More on that, you can extend `setup.py` with [extra dependencies](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) for e.g. the development purposes, and install them by `pip install -e .[dev]`. More like a fancy consequence.

The rest depends on the nature of the scripts.

---

If the scripts are part of the application, they should be installed via the [entry-points in `setup.py`](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

```
# setup.py:
setup(
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'tool1 = mytools.tool1:main',
            'tool2 = mytools.tool2:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

In that case, after `pip install -e .`, they will be in the `bin` folder of the virtualenv, or in `/usr/local/bin` or alike if the system python is used. You can execute them like this:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
tool1 ...

# OR:

~/path/to/venv/bin/tool2
```

The scripts installed this way are fully aware of the virtualenv, to which they were installed, so no activation and no explicit python binary are needed.

---

If the scripts are for the code maintenance, and not semantically part of the application, then they are usually put into `./scripts/` directory (or any other, e.g. `./ci/`), with shebang at the top (`#!/usr/bin/env python`). E.g., `tool1.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def main():
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And executed in the current virtualenv due to this shebang as follows:

```
source .venv/bin/activate
./scripts/tool1.py ...

# OR:

~/path/to/venv/bin/python ./scripts/tool1.py
```

Unlike the scripts installed via the entry points, these scripts do not know about their own virtualenv in any way, so the virtualenv should be activate or proper python used explicitly.

This way is also used when the scripts are non-python, e.g. for the bash scripts.

---

In both cases, the `requirements.txt` file is sometimes used to *pin* the application's & dependencies' versions (with `pip freeze`), so that the deployments would be persistent & predictable. But this is another story — about the deployment of the application, not about the packaging & maintenance.

The `requirements.txt` file is regenerated from time to time to satisfy the new unpinned (i.e. flexible) requirements in `setup.py` and the new package versions available. But usually it is the generated content (despite being committed in the repo), not the content maintained by hand.

---

If you strictly do not want to have `setup.py` for any reason, then either execute those scripts with the modified env var:

```
PYTHONPATH=. python scripts/tool1.py
```

Or hack the `sys.path` from inside:

```
# tools1.py
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

This is exactly what `pip install -e .` does, just done manually on every call, not once with the `.pth` file in the virtualenv. And also this looks hacky.

However, as we know, neither hacky solutions nor the duplicating solutions, especially those duplicating the standard toolkit, are considered "pythonic".